# .MDB set null cell default on creation of new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have another question for anyone willing to help. This should be fairly easy but for whatever reason i cant seem to get it right. Im working with visual studio 08 creating a asp.net website in c#

im trying to have a user register, which is all working great, and have the new user default as a user and not a admin. I am using a .MDB as where everything is stored.

is it possible to do this in my initial sql query?
currently my code looks like

```
strSQL = "Insert into tblUserLogin " +
            "(UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserName, UserPassword, UserAddress, UserCity, UserState, UserZipCode, UserEmail, UserPhone, ) values ('" +
            UserFirstName + "', '" + UserLastName + "', '" + UserName + "', '" + UserPassword + "', '" + UserAddress +
            "', '" + UserCity + "', '" + UserState + "', '" + UserZipCode + "', '" + UserEmail + "', '" + UserPhone +
        "')";
    // set the command text of the command object
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = strSQL;
    // Execute the insert statement
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this will successfully post everything to the .MDB and it will leave the cell under the column SecurityLevel empty.

i attempted to add

```
 "(UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserName, UserPassword, UserAddress, UserCity, UserState, UserZipCode, UserEmail, UserPhone, SecurityLevel=U )
```

but this did not work as i hoped it would. Is there a simple way to have that value SecurityLevel default to U without anyone having to specify it?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly just use a const value `'U'` for `SecurityLevel` column

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLogin " +
         "(UserFirstName, UserLastName, " + 
         " UserName, UserPassword, " +
         " UserAddress, UserCity, " +
         " UserState, UserZipCode, " +
         " UserEmail, UserPhone, SecurityLevel) " +
         "VALUES (" + 
           UserFirstName + "', '" + UserLastName + "', '" + 
           UserName + "', '" + UserPassword + "', '" + 
           UserAddress + "', '" + UserCity + "', '" + 
           UserState + "', '" + UserZipCode + "', '" + 
           UserEmail + "', '" + UserPhone + "', 'U')"; // pass a const value for SecurityLevel column
// the rest of your code goes here
```

On a side note: Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Learn and use prepared (parameterized) statements instead of dynamically building a query strings.

Comment: thank you, that worked great. everything posted properly and that security level was a constant U. Thanks Again!